# Python uses a lot of RAM

Tags: python, python-2.x

I wrote this simple code below to compare the speed of Python and Fortran.

```
import time

start = time.time()

x = 0

for i in range(1,1000000000):
    x = x + i
    x = 0

end = time.time()

print end - start
```

I set x =0 because in Fortran it overflows. When I run the code by Fortran, it returns the answer in 9 seconds, but when I run the code by Python, Python takes all 24GB of my system's RAM and program crashes.

What's the problem?

Comment: 10**9 is going to take a lot of time. :)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary c (compiled with `gcc` with `-O3`) calculates actual sum up to 10^9 in under .25sec on i7 4770 (and `haskell` with `ghc` in 0.65sec).

Comment: On each iteration, if you assign `x = 0`, why bother doing `x = x + i`?

Comment: @ thefourtheye. I thought Python may know there isn't any calculations at all and skip the loop.

Comment: @yashar: Python cannot optimize this; the dynamic nature of the language is such that addition to `x` might have side effects that change from iteration to iteration. If `x` has an `__add__` for example. Note that `range()` need not be the built-in; you can rebind that name to a custom function, so Python has no idea what will be produced from iteration to iteration.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are using `range()`, which produces a list object of all integers in the range. You produced a list object with 10**9 integers in it. On a 64-bit machine that takes about 30GB to hold all those objects, provided your OS will let you allocate that much.

Use the [`xrange()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) instead; this produces an object that only yields numbers as you iterate:

```
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> xrange(10)
xrange(10)
>>> list(xrange(10))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Summing 1 billion integers will still take time on Python; you can use `sum(xrange(10**9))` to delegate most of the work to C code here, but you'll still be producing 1 billion integer objects for the process.

My rather aging 2008 vintage Macbook Pro does this:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('sum(xrange(10**9))', number=3)
38.89629793167114
```

so taking, on average, 13 seconds to produce and destroy 1 billion `int` objects. The actual *summing* is dwarfed by those allocations and deallocations here.

Use [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) for calculations involving large datasets instead; a NumPy `array` holds C datatypes, not Python objects, so will take vastly less memory and the library offers optimized routines that'll beat anything pure Python can do hands-down.

Comment: The xrange works. If each integer takes 4 bytes, then one billion integer take 4 billion or 4 GB. Python takes 24GB on my system. Why is that?

Comment: @yashar: because an `int` is not a simple C integer. It is an object with methods and a reference count, etc, which is unbounded (other than by memory). Numbers < `sys.maxint` take 24 bytes, not 4.

Comment: @yashar No, integers are not pure integers in Python. They are objects here.

Comment: @yashar: The list object to hold the 1 billion references to those 1 billion `int` objects takes an (estimated) 7.45 Gb, the integers a little over 22.35 Gb.

Comment: Does anybody know how can I speed up the code? For example by using scipy or numpy. I have to do heavy calculations. Fortran is fast but Python is much easier and there are better user community and resources for Python. How do scientists use Python for their calculations? To me it seems Python is really slow, but I hear that other use it for HPC.

Comment: @yashar: I say estimated there because I only verified that list objects use 8 bytes per reference on my machine plus a fixed 72 bytes for the object itself, but list objects grow and shrink dynamically in larger steps, as needed.

Comment: @yashar: Numpy arrays can hold actual C integers, not Python `int` objects, and offer many calculations for you in optimized C code. Start there.

Comment: I saved the ``timeit`` version into a file (adding a print) and ran the result with Python 2.7.6 (33.29s), Python 3.4.0b3 (69.09s), and PyPy 2.0.2 (3.72s).  I was surprised at how well PyPy performed.